# Aspectj overwrite an argument of a method

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I'm developing an aspect that checks arguments of setter methods and overwrites empty strings with null value. This is my state so far:

```
@Before("execution(* de.foo.entity.*.set*(..)) && args(java.lang.String)")
public void check(final JoinPoint jp) {
    LOGGER.debug(jp.getSignature().toLongString());
    Object[] args = jp.getArgs();
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        if (args[i] instanceof String && ((String) args[i]).isEmpty()) {
            args[i] = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the overwrite statement `args[i] = null;` does now work! Do anyone know how should I overwrite it?

Cheers,

Kevin

Comment: @Kevin btw you could replace this `if (args[i] instanceof String && ((String) args[i]).isEmpty())` with this `if("".equals(args[i]))`

Comment: Thanks, is it more fast? May because of casting?

Comment: I don't think there's much difference in terms of performance, but my version is more readable and hence less error-prone

Answer (score 34):

I believe you have to implement an around advice, instead of a before advice.

Because you can use proceed with your new arguments:

```
proceed(newArgs);
```

Comment: Thanks, why do I have to impelement an around advice instead of before? Where is the difference excepts that with an around advice I'm able to control execution of a method, catch Exceptions and check return value?

Comment: A before advice gets a copy of the argument array, but it can't modify the original arguments. That's what an around advice is for. Ralph: +1