# What is the AspectJ declarative syntax for overwritting an argument

Tags: java, aspectj

This has been answered before with annotation syntax: [Aspectj overwrite an argument of a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312224/aspectj-overwrite-an-argument-of-a-method)

But I can't figure out how to do it with the AspectJ declarative syntax.
The following should add "Poop" in front of each string in the method but it does not.

```
public aspect UserInputSanitizerAdvisor {

    pointcut unSafeString() : execution(@RequestMapping * * (..));

    Object around() : unSafeString() {
        //thisJoinPoint.getArgs();
        //proceed();
        System.out.println("I'm Around");
        Object[] args = thisJoinPoint.getArgs();
        if (args != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                Object o = args[i];
                if (o != null && o instanceof String) {
                    String s = (String) o;
                    args[i] = "poop: " + s;
                }
            }
        }

        return proceed();
    }

}
```

I can't figure out how to give "proceed()" all the arguments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got the annotation version working:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Aspect
public class UserInputSanitizerAdivsor {

    @Around("execution(@RequestMapping * * (..))")
    public Object check(final ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
        Object[] args = jp.getArgs();
        if (args != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                Object o = args[i];
                if (o != null && o instanceof String) {
                    String s = (String) o;
                    args[i] = UserInputSanitizer.sanitize(s);
                }
            }
        }
        return jp.proceed(args);
    }
}
```

Now I have XSS protection for all my Spring MVC controllers. I was hoping to get the aspectJ syntax working though.

Comment: The traditional AspectJ syntax forces that call made to proceed() in an around advice match those collected by its pointcut. Given your need to update each string argument, the @AspectJ syntax is the only real choice.

Comment: @ramnivas Thanks for confirming my suspicion. Your book is awesome especially chapter 3.

Comment: In my case (Spring 3.2) I had to specify the full name of the RequestMapping annotation to get it to work, like so:

@Around("execution(@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping * * (..))")

Answer (score 0):

Does `return thisJoinPoint.proceed(args);` do what you want?

Comment: You're right. I don't think that you can do it declaratively -> the args() is not flexible enough to handle any arguments.