# Spring AOP capabilities

Tags: spring, spring-aop

i have a bean method : `doXX (String a, String b)`
And, i use this method in an other one

```
class Y {

    X x;
    ...

    doYY () {
      ....
      x.doXX(A, B);
      ...
    }

}
```

i want to change the paramters A, B to specific values
let's suppose that real values are : `TEST, TEST`
I want to set them always : `TEST_en, TEST_en` (i want to add "`_en`")
the method "doXX" is used a lot : so i don't want to change teh code source : it will take a lot of time.

Can i do it with `AOP`?

my container  : `Spring`

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not possible with Spring AOP because doYY and doXX are part of the same class. For the aspect to kick in, you need to call the method from another class. Check out the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-introduction-spring-defn) for all the details

Comment: Thanks for the response : well, yes, it was a fault in the question. i edited it now :)

Comment: Taking into account the edited question, for AOP to work, class X needs to be managed by Spring (where the aspect is applied) and  class Y needs to be injected with the managed class X dependency

Comment: Thanks, i know all of that :). i am asking about AOP :). thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Response :)

[Aspectj overwrite an argument of a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312224/aspectj-overwrite-an-argument-of-a-method)